# Where to find ADO.NET Entity Framework error list?

Tags: entity-framework

Where can I find an ADO.NET Entity Framework error list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here they are.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677004(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Click on Error List (At the bottom of Visual Studio) and then, click on "Message".